# ADO ActualSize vs DefinedSize

Tags: vb6, ado

I am processing an incoming file with an old VB6 program that uses ADO. At some point the input fields are out-of-synch with the field definition.

I looked at each field and saw this:

The incoming field contains "Yes", the DefinedSize (correctly) = 3 but the ActualSize = 2.

How is ActualSize determined? Why is it incorrect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guess:

While you didn't specify the details, I'll assume you are using the Jet OLEDB provider's Text IISAM or the old Desktop ODBC Text Driver with the ODCB-Thunk Provider "OLE DB Provider for ODBC" (or something else similar).

"Yes" will be taken as as Boolean valued column if you had no appropriate schema.ini file to define it as Text instead.  A Boolean is 2 (2 bytes).

Comment: Thanks for responding...

The field was defined as adVarChar with a length of 3 but the problem was at the client's end, not mine.  I reported my finding to them. I don't know what they did but the next incoming file was fine.